# Regex to extract nth element from log entry

Tags: regex

The log data I'm working on is in the following format:

**FORMAT 1:**

```
2015-01-03T18:52:06Z Sat, 03 Jan 2015 18:52:05 GMT GET /images/title2.png 304  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.10 Dublin
```

Fields in the above entry are "space" separated.

**FORMAT 2:**

```
2015-01-03T18:52:06Z|Sat, 03 Jan 2015 18:52:05|GMT|GET|/images/title2.png 304| Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.10|Dublin
```

Fields in the above entry are "vertical pipe line" separated.

**The problem:**
since the number of fields doesn't change, I'm looking to create a regex to extract a field that occurs AFTER the Nth number of "vertical pipe lines" or Nth number of "spaces" all the way to the next encounter of a "vertical pipe line" or a "space".

Comment: The two formats are not interchangeable, since there are also spaces in the data. For instance, `GMT` is in the 7th field in Format 1, but it's in the 3rd field in Format 2. If you need to query a MIX of the two formats, you can't just search for the Nth element.

Comment: Since fields often contain spaces, you must define how to distinguish spaces that are field separators and spaces that are content. As it stands, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

A good job for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk -F'[ |]' '{print $9}' file
```

where $9 is the 9th element (separated by spaces or `|`)

Comment: It should be `-F'[ |]'`. Your solution says the separator is BOTH characters, not either or.

Comment: No, with gnu awk, it's the same output. Not tested others

Comment: The problem is that in the provided data 9th element separated by `|` is not the same as the 9th element separated by ` ` (white space)

Comment: OK, removed the first solution